# Why flex-lexer does not output anything?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am writing a small program for a custom set of tokens. But I do not observe the result of the work. Any ideas?

Here some structures for convenient storage of tokens.
A struct Fragment is needed to display the coordinates of the token in the text (start coords - end coords).

```
%option noyywrap bison-bridge bison-locations
%option noyywrap yylineno 


%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define TAG_IDENT 1
    #define TAG_NUMBER 2
    #define TAG_OPERATION 3

    char * tag_names [] =
    {
        "END_OF_PROGRAM", "IDENT", 
        "NUMBER", "OPERATION"
    };

    struct Position
    {
        int line, pos, index;
    };

    void print_pos(struct Position *p)
    {
        printf("(%d, %d)", p->line, p->pos);
    }

    struct Fragment
    {
        struct Position starting , following ;
    };

    typedef struct Fragment YYLTYPE;

    void print_frag (struct Fragment *f)
    {
        print_pos(&(f->starting));
        printf("-");
        print_pos(&(f->following));
    }
```

A struct Token contains the value of the token. 'init_scanner' reads the text, 'err' shows unrecognized tokens.
If at the beginning of each action you need to perform the same operations (for example, calculate the coordinates of the token), then these operations can
write to the macro YY_USER_ACTION.

```
    struct Token
    {
        char *token;
    };

    typedef struct Token YYSTYPE;

    struct Position cur;

    #define YY_USER_ACTION              \
    {                                   \
        int i;                          \
        yylloc->starting = cur;         \
                                        \
        for (i = 0; i < yyleng; i++)    \
        {                               \
            if (yytext[i] == '\n')      \
            {                           \
                cur.line++;             \
                cur.pos = 1;            \
            }                           \
            else                        \
                cur.pos++;              \
            cur.index++;                \
        }                               \
                                        \
        yylloc->following = cur;        \
    }                                   \

    void init_scanner(char *program)
    {
        cur.line = 1;
        cur.pos = 1;
        cur.index = 0;
        yy_scan_string(program);
    }

    void err (char *msg)
    {
        printf("UNKNOWN ");
        print_pos(&cur);
        printf (": %s\n", msg);
    }
%}
```

Regular expressions:

```
digit       [0-9]
letter      [a-zA-Z]
operation   <=|==|=

%%

({letter}|{digit})*({digit})    {
                                    yylval->token = yytext;
                                    return TAG_IDENT;
                                }

\<{digit}+\>                    {
                                    yylval->token = yytext;
                                    return TAG_NUMBER;
                                }

{operation}                     {
                                    yylval->token = yytext;
                                    return TAG_OPERATION;
                                }

[ \t]+                          {

                                }

\n                              {

                                }

.                               {
                                    err("unexpected character");
                                }

<<EOF>>                         {
                                    return 0;
                                }

%%

#define PROGRAM "dfjdkfsd3 34j3234 23 ="           \
                "    == <= 34234r3"                \
                "ffefef <324234234> <wer444> == "
```

Main func:

```
int main ()
{
    int tag;
    YYSTYPE value;
    YYLTYPE coords;

    init_scanner(PROGRAM);

    do
    {
        tag = yylex(&value, &coords);
        if (tag != 0)
        {
            print_pos(&cur);
            printf (": %s\n", tag);
        }
    }
    while (tag != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the commands that I enter:

```
flex *filename*.l
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
a.exe
```

However nothing happens

Comment: first try to just run, when it runs for the minimal example, then start changing based on your needs.. here is my template, or whatever you may call : https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/64acbbcfdc02a63b39626f3805c338e3

Comment: What did you type as input (if the answer is "nothing" then why do you expect it to do anything?)

Comment: `yylex` returns an integer (token number), but you're trying to print it as a string with `printf (": %s\n", tag);`, which gives undefined behavior (probably a crash, stopping the program before it outputs anything.)

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, you're right! thank you